# Why the snake collide with itself?

Tags: javascript, canvas

In this code, I want to reset the snake when it hits itself like a normal snake game but this code does not work properly. When I eat, I add a snake piece right next to our snake, the `checkSelfCollision()` function detects it as a collision and resets it, so when I eat, my snake resets itself and this is really bad.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

const scoreLabel = document.querySelector('.score')
const highScoreLabel = document.querySelector('.high-score')


const CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width = 500;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height = 500;

class Snake {
  //Other codes

  reset() {
    this.position = {
      x: 143,
      y: 250
    };
    keys.down.pressed = false
    keys.up.pressed = false
    keys.right.pressed = false
    keys.left.pressed = false
    this.velocity = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
    this.body = [];
    this.length = 1;
    score = 0
  }


  checkSelfCollision() {
    for (let i = 1; i < this.body.length; i++) {
      if (
        this.position.x < this.body[i].x + this.width && //Exactly this part
        this.position.x + this.width > this.body[i].x && //
        this.position.y < this.body[i].y + this.height && //
        this.position.y + this.height > this.body[i].y
      ) {
        this.reset();
      }
    }
  }
}



function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  c.fillStyle = "#222";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  snake.update();
  snake.checkSelfCollision();
  food.draw();


  scoreLabel.innerText = `Score: ${score}`
  highScoreLabel.innerText = `High Score: ${highscore}`
}

animate();
```

I tried many things and wanted gpt 3.5 unfortunately I couldn't solve my problem yet. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you provide ALL of the code so I can diagnose the problem?